# NULL Values at Bottom of SQL Table - SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with information containing names and emails. I have to put the rows containing NULL email values at the bottom of the table, but am unable to when I use the SELECT DISTINCT clause. Here is my current syntax:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
     user_index,
     name,
     email
FROM table1
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN email IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

but whenever I try to execute this query, I receive the error message:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

This query works if I take out the DISTINCT clause, but it is necessary in this case. Any tips?

Comment: Do you REALLY need to use distinct at all?

Comment: When we do not use DISTINCT, 100k+ rows are returned. With DISTINCT, only the 9k+ rows we need for this case are returned.

Comment: @CodeJunkie It is interesting why do you need to complicate things because in T-SQL's `order by` nulls treated as the lowest values: [doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). [Working proof](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f053a20354f3a10ee550fb1294b6ed73)

Comment: Suggesting you simply think about your code. Many times people with little experience throw distinct into a query without any particular reason. And it is concerning that so many duplicates exist - but it's your issue to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation instead:

```
SELECT user_index, name, email
FROM table1
GROUP BY user_index, name, email
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN email IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

This is functionally the same as your question.  However, the SQL engine will not get confused about an expression that uses a `distinct` column.